# Recursion in JavaScript to search in heavy JSON

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, recursion, bigdata

I am facing an algorithmic conception problem. With JavaScript language, I have an heavy JSON object of about 11 000 lines, that is the result of the conversion of an HTML file. The structure of the JSON is similar to the one of the DOM, which means that an Object can have a property *children*, a data structure composed of other similar Object. The goal is to search in the JSON and extract the information of the property *itemprop* of the Object that has that property. The *itemprop* attribute is in and Object inside the *attributes* attribute that some of the first mentioned Object have.

**Object Structure**

```
{ type: 'x',
  tagName: 'y',
  attributes: { "itemprop" : "valueWanted" },
  children:
   [ Object, Object, Object] 
}
```

I thought of a recursive algorithm for solution. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with recursion and the next code is not working.

**Recursive Algorithm**

```
var searchAttributesRecursive = function(children) {
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
      if (children[i].hasOwnProperty('children')) {
        return searchAttributesRecursive(children[i].children);
      }
      else {
        if (children[i].hasOwnProperty('attributes')) {
            if (children[i].attributes.itemprop === "valueWanted") {
              console.log('success')
            }

          }
        }
        return; // probably a problem that breaks the loop
      }
    };

searchAttributesRecursive(startingChildren);
```

There is maybe another more effective generic algorithms to get this task done. I am open to suggestions.

**Update**

Thank you for all solutions and explanation provided. More particularly, have a look to @ChrisG's simple solution. Now, I would like to add a special condition in the algorithm.

If I would like to retrieve the data from the next object, outside of the scope of the children where an object has the wantedValue2, do you have an idea how I can access this data? The algorithm would have a special case where it meets wantedValue2, and don't want to extract directly the data of itemprop.

**Object Structure Special Case**

```
{
 "type": "",
  "tagName": "",
  "attributes": {
  "itemprop": "wantedValue"
   },
  "children": [{
      "type": "",
      "content": ""
      }
    ]
  },
 {
  "type": "",
  "content": ""
  }]
  },         
   {
  "type": "",
  "tagName": "",
  "attributes": {},
  "children": [
  {
   "type": "",
    "content": "here"
   }
  ]
```

Comment: search in [JSON](http://json.org/), really? it looks like an object, you are working on. please add the structure, at least a small amount, how it is structured.

Comment: Are you actually looking for the string "itemprop" ?

Comment: @NinaScholz The JSON objects are converted to JS Object, isn't it ? I added the object structure. An Object can have the attributes or children property.

Comment: @epascarello Yes.

Comment: As Nina linked, JSON is just a text format. It's a string. There is no such thing as a "JSON Object" beyond the `JSON` built-in JavaScript object. But yes, `JSON.parse` does convert a JSON string into JavaScript objects. It's a small but important distinction.

Comment: @TheJim01 It is more clear like this, thank you for the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shorter version:

Note that the function expects an array, so if your object is not an array, you have to use `findItemprop([dom], "wanted")`

```js
function findItemprop(data, value, found) {
  if (!found) found = [];
  data.forEach((node) => {
    if (node.attributes && node.attributes.itemprop == value)
      found.push(node);
    if (node.children) findItemprop(node.children, value, found);
  });
  return found;
}

var dom = [{
  tag: "root",
  children: [{
    tag: "header",
    children: [{
      tag: "div"
    }]
  }, {
    tag: "div",
    id: "main",
    children: [{
      tag: "p",
      attributes: {
        itemprop: "wanted"
      }
    }]
  }, {
    tag: "footer",
    children: [{
      tag: "span",
      content: "copyright 2017",
      attributes: {
        itemprop: "wanted"
      }
    }]
  }]
}];

console.log(findItemprop(dom, "wanted"));
```

Comment: If I would like to retrieve the data from the next object, outside of the scope of the children where an object has the wantedValue2, do you have an idea how I can access this data? The algorithm would have a special case where it meets wantedValue2, and don't want to extract directly the data of itemprop.

Comment: @amazingcode12 The solution at the bottom of my answer does exactly that. It is generic, so it can look for any value under any nested property. You should give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Your return will break the loop. You just want to return if it does return:

```
var searchAttributesRecursive = function(children) {
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
        if (children[i].hasOwnProperty('children')) {
            var result=searchAttributesRecursive(children[i].children);
            if(result) return result;//if weve found sth, return
        }

        if (children[i].hasOwnProperty('attributes')) {
            if (children[i].attributes.itemprop === "valueWanted1") {
              console.log('success')
              return children[i];//return sth useful
            }

       }
  }
 return false;//nothing found in this and in all childs
};

var elem=searchAttributesRecursive(startingChildren);
```

This returns the *first* found child. You may want to return an array instead:

```
var searchAttributesRecursive = function(children,result=[]) {
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
        if (children[i].hasOwnProperty('children')) {
            searchAttributesRecursive(children[i].children,result);
        }
        if (children[i].hasOwnProperty('attributes')) {
            if (children[i].attributes.itemprop === "valueWanted1") {
              console.log('success')
              result.push(children[i]);//return sth useful
            }

       }
  }
 return result;//return all results found
};

var arr=searchAttributesRecursive(allElems);
arr.forEach(console.log);
```

Through passing an array as optional parameter it is fast and easy to store the traversal of multiple trees in one result:

```
var arr=[];
searchAttributesRecursive(allElems,arr);
searchAttributesRecursive(allElemsTwo,arr);
```

Comment: Renaming the `children` parameter (not the property) may help alleviate some of amazingcode12's confusion surrounding the recursion. `children[i].children` == confusing, `current[i].children` == less so.

Comment: @TheJim01 i think that would be a good advise to the OP. However, i want his code to look similar so that it is more easy to understand...

Comment: @Jonasw Looks like attributes is not defined (TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemprop' of undefined)

Comment: @amazingcode12 thats impossible. Its checked right in the line before?

Comment: @Jonasw Thanks, it is working now, I forgot to hard-code valueWanted1. You have a little in return results. It should be return result.

Comment: @amazingcode12 yep fixed. Instead of accepting as answer, you can also give an upvote , just sayin ;)

Comment: @Jonasw OK thanks. I would like to upvote and accept every answers. It is really constructive answers, but I have not enough reputation :s

Comment: `if (result) return result` is what I was looking for. A general return will return `undefined` which will cause false positives and screw stuff up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `.some()` function. What this does is it will return true if any iteration returns true, otherwise it returns false. So, for every key in the current object, you will check if the property is `=== 'attributes'`, and if so, you will check the `itemprop` property for the desired value. If the current key is not 'attributes', and is `=== 'children'` it will recurse and check each child object in the same way.

```js
var searchAttributesRecursive = function(obj, valueWanted) {
  if (obj instanceof Object) {
    if (obj.attributes && obj.attributes.itemprop === valueWanted) {
      return true;
    }
    if (obj.children) {
      return obj.children.some(function(_obj) {
        return searchAttributesRecursive(_obj, valueWanted);
      });
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
var obj = {
  type: 'x',
  tagName: 'y',
  attributes: {
    "itemprop": "wantedValue0"
  },
  children: [{
      type: 'x',
      tagName: 'y',
      attributes: {
        "itemprop": "wantedValue1"
      },
      children: []
    },
    {
      type: 'x',
      tagName: 'y',
      attributes: {
        "itemprop": "wantedValue2"
      },
      children: [{
        type: 'x',
        tagName: 'y',
        attributes: {
          "itemprop": "wantedValue3"
        },
        children: []
      }]
    }
  ]
};

console.log("Found 'wantedValue0': " + searchAttributesRecursive(obj, "wantedValue0"));
console.log("Found 'wantedValue1': " + searchAttributesRecursive(obj, "wantedValue1"));
console.log("Found 'wantedValue2': " + searchAttributesRecursive(obj, "wantedValue2"));
console.log("Found 'wantedValue3': " + searchAttributesRecursive(obj, "wantedValue3"));
console.log("Found 'wantedValue4': " + searchAttributesRecursive(obj, "wantedValue4"));
```

**EDIT** - To make this work dynamically and search for `itemprop === wantedValue` in any nested property or nested child property, you can do the following:

```js
var searchAttributesRecursive2 = function(data, valueWanted) {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    return data.some(function(elem) {
      return searchAttributesRecursive2(elem, valueWanted);
    });
  } else if (data instanceof Object) {
    return Object.keys(data).some(function(key) {
      var prop = data[key];
      return prop.itemprop === valueWanted || searchAttributesRecursive2(prop, valueWanted);
    });
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

var obj = {
  type: 'x',
  tagName: 'y',
  attributes: {
    "itemprop": "wantedValue0"
  },
  children: [{
      type: 'x',
      tagName: 'y',
      attributes: {
        "itemprop": "wantedValue1"
      },
      children: []
    },
    {
      type: 'x',
      tagName: 'y',
      attributes: {
        "itemprop": "wantedValue2"
      },
      children: [{
        type: 'x',
        tagName: 'y',
        attributes: {
          "itemprop": "wantedValue3"
        },
        children: []
      }]
    }
  ]
};

console.log("Found 'wantedValue0': " + searchAttributesRecursive2(obj, "wantedValue0"));
console.log("Found 'wantedValue1': " + searchAttributesRecursive2(obj, "wantedValue1"));
console.log("Found 'wantedValue2': " + searchAttributesRecursive2(obj, "wantedValue2"));
console.log("Found 'wantedValue3': " + searchAttributesRecursive2(obj, "wantedValue3"));
console.log("Found 'wantedValue4': " + searchAttributesRecursive2(obj, "wantedValue4"));
```

Comment: but looping over all keys is quite inefficient isnt it?

Comment: @mhodges Thank for your explication about recursion. Unfortunately, the code provided is not working.

Comment: @amazingcode12 Are you passing in the wanted value? This takes it dynamically, it is not hard-coded.

Comment: @Jonasw Yes, I originally made it generic, so it would look for `.itemprop === valueWanted` under any property, but later realized that the OP wanted to only specifically look at the `attributes` and `children.attributes` properties. I'll update my post

Comment: @mhodges Yes, it is passed dynamically.

Comment: @Jonasw Edited, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

Give **Jonas w** the credit for their answer, I'm just tagging on to help correct some of the confusion surrounding the recursion, and hopefully make the it a little easier to understand and work with.

First, you're passing in the array of children. That's fine, but then you have to access each one from its array index as you check them. My recommendation is to make your function handle only one item at a time. (I'm going to use Jonas w's method of collecting nodes, because there may be more than one node with this attribute. I'm also going to add the attribute name as a parameter to make it a little more dynamic.)

```
function searchAttributesRecursive(currentNode, parameterName, results=[]){
}
```

Now you can concentrate on one and only one node at a time. Once it has passed the check, you can move on to the children.

```
function searchAttributesRecursive(currentNode, parameterName, results=[]){
    if(currentNode.attributes && currentNode.attributes[parameterName]){
        results.push(currentNode);
    }
    if(currentNode.children){
        for(var i = 0, len = currentNode.children.length; i < len; ++i){
            searchAttributesRecursive(currentNode.children[i], parameterName, results);
        }
    }
}
```

Calling it like this:

```
var results = [];
searchAttributesRecursive(yourJsObject, "itemprop", results);
```

...populates `results` with nodes which contain the "itemprop" attribute. You can now print the attribute values with a simple loop:

```
for(var i = 0, len = results.length; i < len; ++i){
    console.log(i, results[i].attributes.itemprop);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You have a little typo in the first condition ( one ')' too much and the code is not working: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Looks like currentNode.children is not defined.

Comment: @amazingcode12 Good catch! :) I've edited to fix it.